# How can an NSManagedObject conform to the NSItemProviderReading protocol?

Tags: swift, core-data, drag-and-drop, ios11, swift4

After creating an `NSManagedObject` subclass of a Core Data entity, how can I make it conform properly to the `NSItemProviderReading` protocol? The protocol has a required initializer that must be declared directly in the class. But which designated initializer should `NSItemProviderReading`'s `init(itemProviderData:, typeIdentifier:)` call?

This is what I have below:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Something)
public class Something: NSManagedObject, NSItemProviderReading {

    public override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }

    // MARK: - Item Provider Reading 

    public static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
        return []
    }

    public required init(itemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws {
        // This seems very hack-y…
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        self.init(context: context)
    }
}
```

Is calling `self.init(context:)` really the right way to go here?

Answer (score -1):

To conform to `NSItemProviderReading` protocol requires conformance to the `init` you mentioned and also the static var `readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider`:

```
init(itemProviderData: Data, typeIdentifier: String)

static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String]
```

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemproviderreading) indicates this with the **Required** note.

I don't see anything wrong with your `init` so if it compiles and works with how you plan on using the class I don't see an issue. What I would recommend is using dependency injection to pass Core Data context throughout your app, to the view controllers that need them. That way you don't have to do the annoying `AppDelegate` code every time (and it's safer because you can be sure the context is always available).